# JAVA the efficient way to read a logs from file

Tags: java

I'm looking for most effective way to get all the elements from `List<String>` which contain some `String` value (`"value1"`) for example.

First thought - simple iteration and adding the elements which contains `"value1"` to another `List<String>` But this task must be done very often and by many users.

Thought about `list.RemoveAll()`, but how do I remove all elements which don't contain `"value1"`?

So, what is the way to make it **most efficiently**?

**UPDATE:**

The whole picture - need to need to read the logs from file very often and for multiple users simultaneously. The logs must be filtered by the username from file. each string in file contains username.

Comment: Is the normal way too slow for you?...

Comment: 1) Why bother? This might be a case of premature optimization, so please be more specific. 2) Do the strings just have to _contain_ the value or are they _equal_ to the value, i.e. should "Hi im a String of value1." be removed?

Comment: if it must be `equal`, i would say so. they must  `contain` value

Comment: don't know yet, but i guess tha it maybe be too slow. this is in the logs pasing methods. i get a file to List and need to parse it. FIle is upt to 2 mb. Logs are pushing every 10 seconds. users is up to 50 at same time.

So i guess it can make some trouble if i do this in bad way.

Comment: If that happens very often and when reading you're iterating most of the times (i.e. no direct index access) the most obvious optimization would be to use a `LinkedList`.

Comment: If multiple users access the same list of log statements every time you should consider some form of caching rather than trying to micro-optimize list removal, e.g. keep a list of matching log statements and add any new statements that match. That list could be kept in memory or some other (slower) storage like a file.

Comment: each user have unique log. "value1" is actually a username to get the particular user's log.

Comment: Hint: never make **guesses** about performance. You either have a real problem (that requires analysis), or you don't. You see, if your design requires to make such selections, then some CPU cycles will be used for that; and unless you do outright stupid things, chances are that you are wasting your time. Don't focus on potential subtleties, focus on making the "whole" picture to be efficient.

Comment: Also, if you're getting the list by reading it from a file, that read will take much more time (probably by an order of magnitude more) that iterating through the list afterwards, regardless of what method you use as long as the iteration is linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments it seems like your list is a couple of log statements that should be grouped by user id (which would be your "value1"). If you *really* need to read the logs very often and for multiple users simultaneously you might consider some caching, possibly with grouping by user id.

As an example you could maintain an additional log file per user and just display it when needed. Alterantively you could keep the latest log statements in memory by employing some FIFO buffer which is grouped by user id (could be a buffer per user and maybe another LIFO layer on top of that).

However, depending on your use case it might not be worth the effort and you might just go and filter the list whenever the user requests to do so. In that case I'd recommend reading the file line by line and only adding the matching lines to the list. If you first read everything into a single list and then remove non-matching elements it'll be less efficient (you'd have to iterate more often, shift elements etc.) and temporarily use more memory (as opposed by discarding every non-matching line right after checking it).

Comment: ye i think my question was wrong. probably the more efficient to go deeper in this in the directions you pointed. Yes, i do `really` need to read the logs very often and for multiple users simultaneously

Answer (score 2):

In terms of time efficiency, you cannot get to better result than linear (`O(n)`) if you want to iterate through the whole list.

Deciding between `LinkedList` and `ArrayList` etc. is most likely irrelevant as the differences are small.

If you want a better time than linear to list size, you need to build on some assumptions and prerequisites:

- if you know beforehand what string you'll search for, you can build another list along with your original list containing only relevant records
- if you know you're going to query one list multiple times, you could build an index

If you just have a list on input that someone gave you, and you need to read through this one input once and find the relevant strings, then you're stuck with linear time since you cannot avoid reading the list at least once.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `List`, Use `TreeSet` with provided `Comparator` so that all Strings with "value1" are at the beginning. When iterating, as soon as the string does not contain "value1", all the remaining do not have it, and you can stop to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

The iteration is likely the only way, but you can allow Java to optimize it as much as possible (and use an elegant, non imperative syntax) by employing Java 8's streams:

```
// test list
List<String> original = new ArrayList<String>(){
    {
        add("value1");add("foo");add("foovalue1");add("value1foo");
    }
};
List<String> trimmed = original
    .stream()
    .filter((s) -> s.contains("value1"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(trimmed);
```

**Output**

```
[value1, foovalue1, value1foo]
```

**Notes**

- One part of your question that may require more information is "performed often, by many users" - this may call for some concurrency-handling mechanism.
- The actual functionality is not very clear. You may still have room to optimize your code early by fetching and collecting the `"value1"`-containing `String`s prior to building you `List`

Comment: @user1935987 well that's it then. If you only need the `"value1"`-containing `String`s from that file, you can work on your de-serialization mechanism by pre-filtering the contents (**edit**: details on that implementation would better fit a new question, if so required).

Comment: it is perform only reading from file. so i don't think there will be a probs with  concurrency

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in this I can suggest you the simplest one, I had used.
   Use of an Iterator, makes it easier but if you go with list.remove(val) , where val = "value1" , may give you **UnsupportedOperationException**

List list = yourList; /*contains "value1"*/

```
for (Iterator<String> itr = list.iterator(); itr.hasNext();){
 String val = itr.next();
 if(!val.equals("value1")){

    itr.remove();

}


}
```

Try this one and let me know. :)

Comment: why this is made as not useful?

Comment: Just posting code without any explanations is considered bad style. And "try this one" is not really an explanation. Besides: lazy formatting. Formatting isn't really bad, but it is kinda obvious that you really only did the essential minimum here.